# How To change Grub Boot Setting

Tags: linux, boot, grub, multi-boot

I got Fedora 18 and Windows 7 installed on the same machine, and I want to change Default  boot time from 3sec to 7sec also and the default start-up systems windows 7.
I have used this commande :

> gedit /etc/default/grub
>   And I have edited the file like this :

```
    GRUB_TIMEOUT=10
GRUB_DISTRIBUTOR="$(sed 's, release .*$,,g' /etc/system-release)"
GRUB_DEFAULT=”Windows 7 (loader) on /dev/sda1″
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX="rd.lvm.lv=fedora/swap nomodeset rd.md=0 rd.dm=0 $([ -x /usr/sbin/rhcrashkernel-param ] && /usr/sbin/rhcrashkernel-param || :) vconsole.keymap=fr rd.luks=0 rd.lvm.lv=fedora/root rhgb quiet"
GRUB_DISABLE_RECOVERY="true"
GRUB_THEME="/boot/grub2/themes/system/theme.txt"
```

But it hasn't worked. Any one tell me what's the problem?

Comment: What does "it hasn't worked" mean? What hapens when you boot? Also, your timeout is set at 10, not 7 (typo?), and make sure you use simple double quotes `"`, you have `”` in your question.

Comment: That's mean My Timeout still at 3sec not 10sec like how I configured and the system boot on fedora by default.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

EDIT:  It [seems](https://fedoraproject.org/wiki/GRUB_2) that Fedora 18 uses a modified version of GRUB. I have no experience with this (I recommend you read the [linked page](https://fedoraproject.org/wiki/GRUB_2)) but this should work:

```
grub2-mkconfig -o /boot/grub2/grub.cfg
grub2-install /dev/sda
```

---

After making changes to `/etc/default/grub` you need to regenerate the `grub` configuration file and then re-write grub to your MBR. Assuming your `grub` is installed on the MBR of your primary hard drive, do this after editing the file (as root):

```
update-grub
grub-install /dev/sda
```

Change `/dev/sda` to the appropriate location if that is not where you have installed `grub`.

Comment: `update-grub` is unknown commande when I try it.

Comment: Are you running it as root? If yes, also try specifying the full path (see updated answer).

Comment: Yes I'm logged as root and `update-grub` is unknow

Comment: @Chlebta see my updated answer and [this](https://fedoraproject.org/wiki/GRUB_2) page.

Comment: Thank's a lot :) and Sorry I dont have enough reputation to vote up :/

Comment: GRUB 2 has taken over since Fedora 16 and Ubuntu 9.10 (perhaps for other distros as well, but these are the ones I know about through frequent usage). There's also [BURG](http://code.google.com/p/burg/).

Comment: @Karan, I know, all the above commands are GRUB2 and not legacy GRUB. Fedora is using a modified version (read the link I give in my answer). On my debian system, grub2 (not legacy grub) is installed `update-grub` and `grub-install`. The grub2* commands do not exist. I don't know if they are specific to the Fedora/RedHat world, but they are absent from any Debian based distro I have tried (including various Ubuntus). Personally I use BURG, its purty!

Comment: I don't know about Debian, but AFAIK even `update-grub` calls `/usr/sbin/update-grub`, which in turn calls `/usr/sbin/grub-mkconfig`, so I guess they just updated that on some distros to run `grub2-mkconfig` instead.

Comment: I just compiled grub from source downloaded from the GNU GRUB page. I can confirm that grub2 comes with `grub-mkconfig` and `grub-install` they have probably just changed the names in Fedora.